# Are minimum cut communities maximal?

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, network, clustering

I am looking at the paper [Graph Clustering and Minimum Cut Trees](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.im/1109191029) by Flake et al.

Let $G(V, E)$ be some undirected weighted graph.

**Definition.** Let $s, t\in V$ be given. Let $(S, T)$ be the minimum cut between $s$ and $t$ which minimizes $|S|$. We call $S$ the *community* of $s$ with respect to $t$. (It is noted in the paper that indeed the minimality condition guarantees uniqueness of $S$.)

**Definition.** Given some $\alpha\ge 0$, we define the *expanded graph* $G_\alpha$ to be $G$ with an additional node $t$, the *artificial sink*, which is connected to all other nodes in $V$ by edges of constant weight $\alpha$.

Assume now we have chose some $\alpha\ge 0$ and therefore $G_\alpha$. For convenience, I quote the following lemma from the paper.

**Lemma 3.9.** *Let $v_1, v_2\in V$, and $S_1, S_2$ be their communities with respect to $t$ in $G_\alpha$. Then either $S_1$ and $S_2$ are disjoint or one is a subset of the other.*

I now want to prove the following statement, which is included implicitly in the text below the lemma:

**Statement.** *Let $v_1\in V$, and $S_1$ be the community of $v_1$ with respect to $t$. Let $v_2\in S_1$ (!), and $S_2$ be the community of $v_2$ with respect to $t$. Then $S_2\subseteq S_1$.*

This is necessary to justify the heuristic approach in that section of the paper.

I already see, of course, that in the setting of the above statement, we have either $S_1\subseteq S_2$ or $S_2\subseteq S_1$ by the lemma, as $S_1\cap S_2\neq\emptyset$.

**Questions.** (i) Why does the statement hold? It looks so easy. Hints instead of full explanations are particularly appreciated! (ii) Is it important that $t$ is an "artificial sink", or would the same results hold when $t$ was any fixed "normal" node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the authors are using the proof of Lemma 3.9 instead of its statement. The proof actually justifies the lemma you need:

**Lemma 3.9***. Let $v_1, v_2 ∈ V$, and $S_1$, $S_2$ be their communities with respect to $t$ in $G_\alpha$. If $v_1\in S_2$ then $S_1\subseteq S_2$, and if $v_2\in S_1$ then $S_2\subseteq S_1$. Otherwise, $S_1$ and $S_2$ are disjoint.

Although it is not mentioned in the paper, the proof of Lemmas 3.9, 3.9*, and your statement depend on the submodular inequality for cuts. Assume that all edges of $G$ have been given non-negative weights and let $w(S)$ be the total weight of edges having exactly one end in the vertex set $S$. Then

$$w(S\cap T) + w(S\cup T) \leq w(S) + w(T).$$

If we replace $T$ with its complement, we get

$$w(S-T) + w(T-S) \leq w(S)+w(T).$$

To prove the lemmas, apply the above inequalities to $S_1$ and $S_2$ in each of the various cases, using their minimality and the observation that $w(S\cup T)\geq w(S), w(T)$.

(If you haven't seen submodularity before, it is worth proving these inequalities on your own — it's a fairly simple counting argument. Submodularity is a fundamental and ubiquitous tool in structural graph theory, which is why I assume the authors neglected to mention it explicitly.)

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, applying this inequality to $S_1$ and $S_2$ and using the fact that they both minimize $w(S_i)$ and $|S_i|$, respectively, the statement follows easily. However I don't see that I need the above lemma for that...

Comment: The submodular inequality is actually the tool you use to prove both the lemma and your statement (although the paper doesn't mention it explicitly). I've expanded my answer to address Lemma 3.9, whose proof is stronger than its statement.